# Paypal Recurring Payment - Charge user with outstanding amount in the middle of month

Tags: paypal

I have the following scenario in which i want to charge the user in the middle of month before upgrading the plan

A $10 monthly recurring payment profile is created which start from 03/19.
On 03/30 the user upgrades its plan that costs $5 more a month. All is well, I can update the recurring payment to $15 a month, so on 04/19 the user will get charged $15.
Since the user upgrades his current plan in the middle of a billing cycle, I would like to charge the user with the outstanding amount between 03/30 when the plan is upgraded, and until 04/19 when the new billing cycle kicks in (roughly that would amount to about $2.70 in this case).
I have tried the BillOutstandingAmount Classic Api but it does works as it displays an error i.e., Outstanding Amount must be greater than 0 even if the amount is greater than zero.

Is there any other way to charge the user before switching the plan in the middle of month.

Any help regarding this problem is highly appericiated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BillOutstandingAmount is only for billing amounts that are outstanding because the scheduled payment failed for one reason or another.  That API won't allow you to simply process some random new amount.

To do that you'll need to work with reference transactions.  The [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) API can be used for that.  You basically pass in a previous transaction ID (or Billing Agreement ID) along with any amount you need to charge and it'll process it using the same payment details that were used on that original transaction.

If you're setting up your recurring payments profiles using Payments Pro then you can simply pass in the transaction ID from a previous transaction and that will work fine.

If you're setting up your recurring payments profiles with Express Checkout, though, you'll need to adjust your SetExpressCheckout request to include a billing agreement, and then you'll use the Billing Agreement ID you get back from that in the DoReferenceTransaction request.  If that's the case you won't be able to do that with any current profiles since no billing agreement was included, but it would work for new sign-ups from that point on.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, Its really very helpful. With this i have successfully implemented the Recurring payments using Direct Payment.